# Inductive proof parity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $a$ be an integer. I want to prove by induction that for all $n$ such that $n$ is a positive integer, that $a^n$ and $a$ have the same parity.

my work:

I know the base case is when $n = 1$, and $a^1 = 1 = 1$.

I know the induction step is when $n = k$ for some arbitrary positive integer $k$. And I want to prove that $a^{n+1}$ and $a$ have the same parity.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: The parity of $a$ is fixed. So you just have to show that the parity of $a^n$ does not depend on the exponent since the case $n=1$ is obviously true. Just consider two cases : $(1)$ a is even $(2)$ a is odd

Comment: $\text{even}*\text{even} = \text{even}$, $ \text{odd}*\text{odd} = \text{odd}$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $a^n$ and $a$ have the same parity. Then, since\begin{align}a^{n+1}-a&=(a^{n+1}-a^n)+(a^n-a)\\&=a^n(a-1)+(a^n-a),\end{align}since $a^n(a-1)$ is even (one of the factors is even), and since $a^n-a$ is even too, $a^{n+1}-a$ is even, which means that $a^{n+1}$ and $a$ have the same parity.

But, of course, it is far more simple to say that if $a$ is odd, then $a^n$ is odd, and that if $a$ is even, then $a^n$ is even.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this. Why the downvote?